# Parsing xml in vb

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a pretty generic xml file which I'm looking to parse, however, I'm not too sure where to find such a tutorial to read data from xml files. I'm looking to create a card game, and I'm looking to be able to create my own cards. I've already created the file that creates the cards but now I have to read them.

This is the format of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cards>
<Card>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>Cardsname</Name>
<Type>teetete</Type>
<Image>1gc.jpg</Image>
<Description>test</Description>
</Card>
</Cards>
```

As you can see, theres a root node called 'Cards' which contains all of the cards.
I need to access this node and find all of the 'Card' nodes and their children (id, name, type, image). How would I access the text within these?

EDIT:
Just figured out how to access it but can't figure out how to loop it. If i wanted to access multiple elements, how would I do so?

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim output As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Using reader As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml")
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Card")
        reader.MoveToFirstAttribute()
        reader.ReadToFollowing("ID")
        output.AppendLine("ID: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Name")
        output.AppendLine("Name: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Type")
        output.AppendLine("Type: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Image")
        output.AppendLine("Image: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Description")
        output.AppendLine("Description: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
        MessageBox.Show(output.ToString)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `XMLReader`. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) for an example.

Comment: There are at least several approaches. The most popular would probably be Serialization and LINQ to XML.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the help! Just added a bit more code if you'd be able to figure out how to loop this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a convenient way of handling things in your case. Consider this example:

```
Dim xml As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                       <Cards>
                         <Card>
                           <ID>1</ID>
                           <Name>Cardsname</Name>
                           <Type>teetete</Type>
                           <Image>1gc.jpg</Image>
                           <Description>test</Description>
                         </Card>
                       </Cards>
```

Yes, you can paste raw xml into your code like this.

Then your collection of cards can be accessed using this approach:

```
Dim cards As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xml.Root.Elements("Card")
```

For a particular card, you get its properties like this:

```
Dim cardID As String = cards(0).Element("ID").Value
```

As a side note, you would probably be using `XDocument.Load` or `XDocument.Parse`, instead of having your XML inline with your code. Rest is the same.